# Given dictionary as function argument, need to get its key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary which include only one key-value pair. The dictionary is passed to function, where I need to get dictionary's key name

```
mydict = {'foo':'bar'}

def myfunc(mydict):
    return mydict.key #need to return key name, i.e. 'foo'
```

I found extremely ugly solution, but my soul asks for beauty.

UPD: thanks, @TigerhawkT3. It will be great if I could check whether value of the key is not empty.

Comment: What do you mean, "if the value of the key is not empty"?

Comment: I mean, if it contains an empty string or None, like so: `mydict = {'foo':''}`

Comment: `if next(iter(mydict.values())):...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way to do this is with `next(iter(...`, which creates an iterator out of the iterable and takes the next value:

```
>>> mydict = {'foo':'bar'}
>>> next(iter(mydict))
'foo'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do `mydict.key` because dictionaries can have any number of keys.  If you can guarantee that there is only one key, use `next(iter(mydict))`.  If you want to get a list of the keys, use `list(mydict)`.